# Getting this error: 'Building Workspace' has encountered an error. Errors occurred during the build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, pom.xml

Im using eclipse neon with maven 3.5.0.
Anytime I make some changes to the pom file and try saving it, it throws me this error. I am unable to fix it and hence unable to proceed ahead in my project.

[image: Building Workspace Error]

Comment: First try to build on command line only...

Comment: Looks like you have 121 Java errors. Fix them first.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779141/eclipse-throws-nullpointerexception-during-maven-update)?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the current version of Eclipse (Eclipse Oxygen)?

Comment: Delete all your local repositories and build project once again

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem happening coz im unable to download the dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3895

The problem is the empty file selenium-java-3.4.0-javadoc in the javadoc file. Java cannot handle such entries currently (fixed for JDK9): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048990

The empty file should be removed from the javadoc file.