# Maven update results in NullPointerException. Where to find the stacktrace/cause?

Tags: eclipse, maven, nullpointerexception, stack-trace, m2eclipse

First a tiny bit of background:

- I'm working on a large application for which the development started around 2008 (so as you can imagine, it's huge with loads of dependencies of which part are already unsupported/outdated)
- I have a git branch with the current (developer) version, as well as a bunch of other branches with earlier versions (and some other branches like master and such, but those are irrelevant for now)

These days, every time I switch from the current branch to an older branch to do some hotfixes, the Maven update and Clean build work fine. However, when I switch back after the hotfix is done to the current branch, and do a Maven update, I get the following error:

[image]

This is a pretty well-known error based on some earlier stackoverflow questions I saw. Most answers you'd find will say to [remove the entire `.settings` and `.project` files, and re-import the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19941737/1682559); or to [remove the `.metadata` of your workspace, and restart Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24015976/1682559). In the past I remembered using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35266937/1682559) of only deleting the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` file of the workspace, so the damage to your Eclipse project settings is limited. However, it doesn't always work, and I'm also getting a bit tired of getting this exception every single time I switch back and forth from a branch..

Note that I've already tried a bunch of other things without much avail:

- Removing my entire .m2 folder and letting it download everything from our Nexus again
- Looked in the Maven Console to see what is being logged, which isn't anything related to this NPE unfortunately
- Do the Maven Update Project both with or without "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" enabled
- Do a Clean Build with the "Update Snapshots" enabled

What I'm mainly looking for right now is a stacktrace of this NullPointerException, so I can (hopefully) fix this issue at the core of the problem, instead of using all these workarounds like deleting Eclipse/Maven folders and/or settings (which only work halve of the time anyway)..

It gives a NullPointerException, so I assume I should be able to see the stacktrace of this NullPointerException to determine the cause somewhere in an Eclipse log or console, shouldn't I?

Is there perhaps a mvn command flag/argument I could use? Or is this NullPointerException an issue of Eclipse rather than Maven?

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Error log

Comment: @helospark Thanks, that's what I was looking for! Apparently it gives the error `at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualFolder.getFirstTaggedResource(VirtualFolder.java:185)`, which is also known in [some other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779141/eclipse-throws-nullpointerexception-during-maven-update), as well as a [known Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480643). I tried [this approach](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1091578/), but suggested line is getting removed by Eclipse. But at least I can continue.