# Eclipse unable to resolve maven test dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, mocking

I'm running into a bit of a strange issue with eclipse 4.18 that I'm hoping someone can help me with. My project is a jetty webapp that does some communication with an external server over FTP. I'm using mockftpserver (https://mockftpserver.org/) to assist with unit testing the code that needs to communicate with the FTP server.

I have the library dependency defined in the pom as

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockftpserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>MockFtpServer</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

I then have an import defined in my test class like

```
package my.project.test;
import org.mockftpserver.fake.FakeFtpServer;

public class TestGuiceModule extends GuiceModule {
}
```

Nothing too exotic going on, and maven seems to be able to run the compile. Eclipse however does not seem to be able to see the library. I have a bunch of errors along the lines of

> The import org.mockftpserver cannot be resolved.

I double checked the build path and I can see the library listed under 'Maven Dependencies' and the package structure of the jar matches my import statement. Even stranger, I have other 'test' scoped dependencies in the pom.xml and eclipse is detecting those just fine. I'm at a bit of a loss as to why it is having an issue with this one particular library. Any suggestions on what I could do to track this down?

Comment: Where is the source file located in your project?

Comment: The code with the import is located in src/test/java/my/project/test

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it or make sure to have the correct `requires...` statements. By the way, your Eclipse is 4 releases behind. Please upgrade.

Comment: I don't have a module-info.java and I'm not sure what you mean by a requires statement.

Comment: When having a `module-info.java`, it must contain `requires` statements for directly used dependencies. I cannot reproduce what you are saying, import statement works fine with that dependency. Please show a complete https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to solve this by deleting my settings folder and .project file and reimporting the project (see: [Eclipse throws NullPointerException during Maven update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779141/eclipse-throws-nullpointerexception-during-maven-update)).

The project was originally created in an older version of eclipse, but I thought I would be ok since I was checking out a fresh copy from the git repo. Apparently something must have gotten checked in that the newer version of eclipse didn't like.